# Is there any way to stay on same bootstrap modal after submitting the form?

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, asp-classic

```
<form id="upload_form" method="post" action="uploadfile.asp">
                <div class="row">
                    <input type="file" name="file" id="file" accept=".csv,.xls"/></span>    
                    <input type="submit" value="submit">
                </div>             
</form>
```

This form is on bootstrap modal.

uploadfiles.asp, I am using FreeASPUpload class that I got from internet.

```
if Upload.UploadedFiles.Count = 1 Then

Response.redirect("/admin/login_list_import.asp?file_upload=1-0")

else

Response.write("No files sent or only one file required. Script is OK!<br>") ' Say to Flash that script exists and can receive files

End IF
```

when I submit the form it redirect me to login_list_import.asp page.

I want to stay on the same modal after submitting the form. 
Is there any way to do this?

Comment: I tried ajax but it did not work for me

Answer (score 0):

I think when you are redirected to the page

login_list_import.asp?file_upload=1-0

using the same condition (file_upload=1-0), you can manually fire the js code to open the modal window on page load

For example

```
<%
if Request.Querystring("file_upload")="1-0" then
%>

  <script type='text/javascript'>

     $( document ).ready(function() {
        $('#divmodal').modal('show');
     });

  </script>

<%
end if
%>
```

Answer (score 0):

Send the Formdata via Ajax-Request.